# Este Error se genera en visual studio code al intentar ejecutar un Emulador creado con Android Studio para ejecutar código de flutter

Tags: flutter, vscode

Me arroja estos error.

Ya verifique la ruta y es la correcta y me aparece un emulador que yo cree con Android Studio.

Something went wrong fetching you Android emulators! Make sure your path is correct. Try running this command in your terminal: "false\emulator" -list-avds source: Android iOS emulator (extension)

Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT source: Android iOS emulator (extension)

Make sure your Windows path is set correctly! Example: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator source: Android iOS emulator (extension)

Comment: Cuando corres ese comando que te pide, que aparece?

Comment: Al correr el comando que me pide me bota los emuladores creados en esa ruta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo idea es que lo pongas en la raíz de tu disco de almacenamiento, la entrada dart en tu ruta resuelve a C:\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe, que no está dentro de tu actual revisión de Flutter SDK en C:\flutter. Considera añadir C:\flutter\bin al principio de tu ruta.

Después intentar correr los comandos recomendados para comprobar que todo esté bien.
[image: Mensaje que respalda lo que dije, el mensaje en la consola de Windows PowerShell]

Después de hacer esto, abrí el cmd de powersheel, entonces, abrí android studio, y no funciona aún.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).